# Keyboard shortcuts are not active in Visual Studio with Resharper installed

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

I have **Visual Studio** 2012 + **Resharper** 7.1.1000.900 + **StyleCop** 4.7.44  installed.

The problem is that **no shortcuts** are active since Resharper was installed.

For example: I can still rename via 'Refactor > Rename'. But shorcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does nothing.

I tried setting **Resharper keyboard scheme** to 'Visual Studio' in 'Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus'

Is there any other way to activate shortcuts? Thanks.

Comment: No shortcuts? Not even Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V?

Comment: Well, that's somehow a feature of Resharper, replacing Visual Studio shortcuts. It should have asked you politely though. Maybe you missed the dialog boxes asking for permissions or options. You should uninstall it, repair Visual Studio and reinstall.

Comment: I believe that the VS studio shortcut is 'Ctrl+R,R'. i.e. Hold Ctrl + R (Double press). Does this work?

Comment: Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are working.
Ctrl+R,R - causes the message 'The key combination (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) is not a command'.
I've uninstalled both Resharper and VS. Then installed both again.
(before the message was 'The key combination (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) is bound to command (.Resharper.Rename) which is not currently available.')

Comment: Check out your *Resharper license*, it can work incorrectly if it's expired or unlinked.

Answer (score 507, accepted):

I would first try resetting all Visual Studio settings (**Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings**), then go to the **Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus** and re-apply the keyboard shortcut scheme.

I had to do something similar once.

Comment: had this problem after a VS update.  Reset VS to standard then re-applied Resharper override scheme.  All good again. Thanks

Comment: @Divine: You down voted me because my suggestion for a problem you don't have didn't help you? Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: This is going to reset *all* your VS settings, right? Not just the keyboard shortcuts. Because that's kind of bad.

Comment: @DCShannon Yep. Desperate situations call for desperate measures. :) You can always export your settings before resetting them.

Comment: The concern in the comment from @DCShannon is valid. This will reset **all** your VS settings, which includes many things beyond just the keyboard mappings. A better option is to reset just your keyboard mapping scheme at **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard**

Comment: @BitMask777 Did you actually have this problem and did that actually fix it? Or are you just theorizing? Because if that does actually work, I agree, that's a better approach.

Comment: This worked for me, but one thing is Resharper sets keys based on context, so for example ctrl-alt-p I wanted for attached process, and while the global was set correctly, Resharper mapped the key combo to something else IF in the text editor, so I had to manually change that one

Comment: While this is a solution, the first step (resetting all settings) is a bit drastic and will be unnecessary for many users. See the more conservative suggestion by ND72--that advice worked for me or more than one workstation, and it affects only ReSharper settings and not Visual Studio settings.

Comment: If this didn't work for you check the **Resharper License**, it might fail silently if something's wrong with the licensing.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS, THIS IS GOING TO RUIN YOUR PROJECT. 
All settings are going to gone, including any hidden ones about building etc.
If you have no idea about keyboard settings, probably you won't be about to fix the build failures after the full reset. Very bad idea, close to just run `rm -rf /`.

Answer (score 176):

These steps worked for me:

1. Setting to Resharper / Options / KeyBoard & Menus / **None** / Apply
2. Resharper / Options / KeyBoard & Menus / **Set to Visual Studio** /
   Apply and Save

Comment: Worked for me. I'd suggest trying this solution before blowing away ALL setting as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me too, with VS 2017 and ReSharper 2017.1. I definitely recommend to try this out before using the solution in the accepted answer, which has unwanted side effects.

Comment: This worked for me for Resharper 2017.3.2 and VS 2015

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2019 Pro with ReSharper  2018.3.4.

Comment: This answer all the way!

Comment: Still valid all the way in 2021. VS 2019 Pro, R# 2019.2. I exited and re-ran VisualStudio between steps to play it safe.

Comment: For anyone using VS2022 / R#2022.3 the path is Extensions > ReSharper > Options > Keyboard > Shortcut Scheme, but after that, the steps worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I have VS2022 with resharper installed but disabled and the shortcuts were not working. I re-enabled resharper, i put keyboard schema to none, re-disabled it and shortcuts in VS are working fine now!

Comment: tf is that, why does it even work still in 2023..? Thanks dude!

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and reset didn't fix it. Then the resharper support helped me.
Solution was very simple!
I'm from Russia and usually my default keyboard is Russian. In control panel | language settings | change keyboard - I changed default keyboard to English. Then reapply settings in VS: Resharper|Options|Keyboard&Menus - apply R# scheme. And the problem was fixed :)

Comment: Indeed, I have Dutch & English enabled. When I applied the R# theme, the keyboard switched from Dutch to English. I switched back to Dutch before hitting the Save button. This did it for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had a very difficult time getting this working one under VS2015 one day.  After the initial install everything was working, but I come in this morning and my keyboard shortcuts don't work.  Going through Resharper's **Environment > Keyboard & Menus** didn't work; reinstalling Resharper didn't work.  Even deleting every configuration from Resharper's AppData folder didn't work.

So what did work?  Going to Visual Studio's **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard** and clicking *Reset*.  After I did that, then Resharper's schemes would take.

Comment: The problem is that this is just a temporary solution. Sometimes I have to repeat what you've described several times a day.

Answer (score 12):

**Without resetting Visual Studio settings** :

I found simply

- **ReSharper > Options > Keyboards**
- **Apply Scheme** button
- **Save** button

**Brought back my lost ReSharper keyboard commands** without messing with my VS settings.

(Visual Studio Community 2017 + ReSharper Ultimate)

Comment: This fixed my issue, too, but I found I had to restart VS before it worked.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively - make sure that Resharper is enabled. My visual studio didn't update my Resharper license information, so when opening the resharper menu (after trying to figure out why my shortcuts stopped working!), the was a menu item "Why is Resharper disabled?"
Clicking on the menu item opens up a dialog, which then automatically resolved the license.
The next question for Jetbrains is why do I have to open the dialog for the thing to automatically renew??

Comment: After hours of wasting time reinstalling everything, THIS turned out to be my problem. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Yes--after trying several options listed, I realized that my license had expired. Updating it fixed the issues. Just a bummer that there isn't better notification of the expiry.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what has happened to me. I think it is not the best user experience that Resharper does not warn you that changes will not take effect when you try to change its setting with it disabled.

Answer (score 9):

This one worked for me

`RESHARPER > OPTIONS > select visual studio (Under Keyboard Shortcuts)`

[image: VS + Resharper]

Answer (score 8):

You can look at the Visual Studio Integration options for ReSharper by...

1. Select **ReSharper > Options...** from the Visual Studio menu
2. Select the **Visual Studio Integration** item on the Options window

The bottom of the page gives instructions on how to reset the keyboard scheme.

If that doesn't work, I would re-install ReSharper.

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2015 RC. The important step is mentioned in the ReSharper Options > Keyboard & Menus panel: reset the keyboard bindings in Visual Studio options first, before trying to reapply the ReSharper keyboard scheme.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 and Resharper 9.2

**"Resharper 9 keyboard shortcuts not working in Visual Studio 2015"**

I had tried all possible resetting and applying keyboard schemes and found the answer from Yuri Fedoseev.

My Windows 10 language configuration only had Swedish in the language preferences "Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language"

**The solution** was to add English(I chose the US version) in the language list. 
And then go to Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus > Apply Scheme. (perhaps you do not even need to apply the scheme)

Answer (score 3):

Try this steps:

1) Resharper > `Options` > `Keyboard & Menus`

Then point choose:

- `Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items` (Check)
- `Visual Studio` (Check)

Then click on `Apply Scheme and Save`.

2) `Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Keyboard`

- Click `Reset`
- Click `Ok`

Answer (score 2):

Just a comment on this issue. After I installed Visual Studio 2015 RTM all my resharper shortcuts were gone. (I had them working just fine with RC) A few of my colleagues were having the exact same issue with Visual Studio 2012.

I tried all the suggestions in here but none worked. The way I found to solve this was to: go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings , select the "Import selected environment settings" and in my case use the Settings I had from my RC installation (you can see that there are files with parts of a date as the filename like: CurrentSettings-2014-09-22). For my colleagues problem I basically sent them my .vssettings that I had that was working on my local VS2012 installation.

This effectively solved the shortcut problem. Further investigation in my case showed that although I applied the Resharper shortcuts they were never bound to the actual shortcut key thats why resetting stuff never worked.

Answer (score 2):

1. Reset or apply the scheme
2. Save
3. Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

Note for NVidia users: GeForce Experience silently overrides some hotkeys (for example Alt+F7) and ReSharper stops to handle them. So you need to disable or remap nvidia hotkeys first.

Comment: i unticked enable 'something' overlay in the geforce settings, and my resharper works again, ta

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was in **Resharper License**. It has been delinked from my account for some reason and it said that the license is invalid. When I linked it again to my JetBrains account it started to work properly after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working again by going into VS 2015 Options-> Keyboard, then hitting Reset. Then go back to resharper keyboard options and selecting the ReSharper scheme and hitting apply.

Comment: That worked for me as well. It's the method suggested in this Jet Brains forum thread:

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206010649-VS2015-and-keyboard-shortcuts?page=1#community_comment_205817735

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem. I followed the approved answer. I have done but it was not working, because my keyboard format was different. It was in Bengali keyboard. But later I have changed my keyboard layout and tried in this way.

`Resharper > Options > Keyboard & Menus > Apply scheme > Save`.

Then it was working fine. But whenever I change my keyboard English-US to Bengali then it changes again and I need to do reconfigure.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio:
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Reset

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

If the left corner shows it is a "Miscellaneous Files" on Visual Studio, you will want to make sure the current file is included in the project or not first, otherwise, ReSharper has no way to figure out the shortcut or even work. Visual Studio sometimes will not include the files in csproj

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could find said first try and do a VS-Repair. If that doesn't work then do this.

> Restart Windows and in safe mode, run devenv /safemode in Visual
>   Studio 2005 Command Prompt.   If in safe mode this issue disappeared,
>   the cause should be third-party applications, services or Visual
>   Studio Add-ins.   Please also try devenv /resetsettings or devenv
>   /setup in Command Prompt.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907965

http://forums.asp.net/t/1103223.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many of the above issues and still had installation problems.

It turns out that downloading the full version (not the web installer), and running it as administrator finally got the latest version installed with no errors in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to reset VS setting (tools > option > Export Settings > Reset all settings)
and click Resharper button(Option > Environment > Keyboard&Menu > Keyboard shortcuts)
select item you want to use and apply scheme.

It's work for me on visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the tricks in this thread and others, but just couldn't get this to work in Visual Studio 2022. Finally I tried to update to the latest version of ReSharper (2022.2.3 in my case) and suddenly it all worked!

Answer (score -1):

I had to delete the

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\JetBrains folder. Then is was able to enable the shorcuts again.

Comment: My issue was not really the same (no keyboard shorcuts because resharper was not able to load at all after a checkout) but this solution fixed it.

Comment: Please be careful. This can break Visual Studio, irrespective of Resharper. Also, this can prevent you from doing a clean uninstall-reinstall.