# ReSharper 8 and VIsual Studio 2012 - hotkey not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I use Visual Studio 2012(RUS) and ReSharper 8.0.14. Hotkey not work. I  watching this [topic][Keyboard shortcuts are not active in Visual Studio with Resharper installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364059/keyboard-shortcuts-are-not-active-in-visual-studio-2012-with-resharper-installed), but don't help. Any ideas?

Comment: JetBrains have a great technical support (IMO), contact them, not us!

Comment: @tnw [Explicitly ON TOPIC are "software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as the [two thousand questions about ReSharper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) indicate...

Comment: Which hotkey doesn't work? A Resharper one or a Visual Studio one?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-388094). And looks like it is going to be fixed in ReSharper 8.1.

As workaround for R# 8.0:

1. use any Imported*.vssettings file from here %localappdata%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.0\vs11.0\
2. Replace all "Текстовый редактор" with "Text Editor"
3. save the file and import it here Tools | Import and Export settings.

Comment: Thank you, but  I don't find  "Текстовый редактор"(there is no)

Comment: Strange, but anyway, try to import this [vssettings file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20411351/Imported-13-10-19-17-20-57.vssettings). If it does not help, please share the latest Imported*.vssettings file you found in mentioned directory.

Answer (score -1):

Seriously, I was also a victim of Jetbrain Resharper, VS 2012 was pretty slow, though features are great..but sorry to say it bog down the VS tool terribly! :(. Their support never say their product is slow, instead they would point to Higher version of OS...etc, I have WIN7, 8GB RAM..etc ...still the same...

@Arran Oct 7 '13 at 15:11 - dont write a comment with a "drunk" attitude, people turn to Stackoverflow with a great hope, Help to keep the hope!