# Visual Studio 2013 shortcuts nor working neither resetting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-addins, shortcut

My VS2013 shortcuts were working fine and I also use some addons for my productivity. But lately I observed my most of the default VS shortcuts weren't working anymore (e.g. Ctrl K, Ctrl C for commenting, Ctrl K Ctrl T for viewing hierarchy).

I tried resetting the keyboard shortcuts to **DEFAULT** but that didn't work as well. (Using the foll. steps)

*Menu:  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> RESET Button -> Confirm Yes.*

I'm unsure why the shortcuts aren't still working.

The list of the installed addons (that may be fudging up the shortcuts, I tried combinations to disable them and try again but in vain)

[image: Snap1]

[image: Snap2]

[image: Snap3]

Can anybody please help?

Comment: By addons do you mean Resharper or anything alike?

Comment: @Ankit: I haven't installed resharper but I have provided the list of addons that are currently installed on VS on my machine.

Comment: My bad, I missed that. Possibly any of these tools have their own shortcuts that have been made the default & playing havoc with the default VS shortcuts. I know you have reset the shortcuts but still the problem persists. Check these two links - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/05/keyboard-shortcuts-reset-all-your-shortcuts-vstiptool0064.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364059/keyboard-shortcuts-are-not-active-in-visual-studio-2012-with-resharper-installed

Comment: I am still attempting the diagnose and found that, specifically, CTRL+K is not getting picked up by VS. Unsure of any other key combos.

Comment: @Ankit: Already tried first link - Not useful to me. Second link- not applicable since I don't have resharper.