# Resharper Ctrl-T mapping lost

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, keyboard

I seem to have lost the Resharper <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> mapping to find classes quickly, I tried the solutions described here:

[Keyboard shortcuts are not active in Visual Studio with Resharper installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364059/keyboard-shortcuts-are-not-active-in-visual-studio-with-resharper-installed)

Specifically the accepted answer:

> I would first try resetting all Visual Studio settings (Tools > Import
>   and Export Settings > Reset all settings), then go to the Resharper >
>   Options > Keyboard & Menus and re-apply the keyboard shortcut scheme.

And this:

> Setting to Resharper / Options / KeyBoard & Menus / None / Apply and
>   Save
>
> and then
>
> Resharper / Options / KeyBoard & Menus / Set to Visual Studio / Apply
>   and Save

The latter doesn't do anything (no noticeable positive result), the former results in the following:

> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord.

So it looks like VS is trying to handle the command, not Resharper.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> however works as expected, so it's not that Resharper is totally detached.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What shortcut is mapped to ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoType in Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard? By the way what R# version do you use: ReSharper | Help | About JB ReSharper Ultimate?

Comment: @Alexander: `Resharper.Resharper_ResharperUnitTestDebugContext (Ctrl+T, Ctrl+D (Global))` and version 9.0.

Comment: Looks like "ReSharper 2.x/IDEA" scheme is used instead of "Visual Studio" one. Please check which radio button is selected here ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus.

Comment: @Alexander: Correct! If I switch to the Visual Studio radiobox, leave and use Ctrl+T, I get the `Shortcut conflict` window, what option should I chose then?

Comment: Choose "Use ReSharper command" radio button (you do not need to select any items in the list at the top) in the opened popup(check "Apply to all ReSharper shortcuts").

Comment: By the way, just to avoid possible obstacles in the future, the best way is to reset all shortcuts in "Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard" first. Then apply "Visual Studio" scheme in R# Options.

Comment: Yay, works! Please combine your last two responses as an answer so I can flag it as such.

Comment: So this still happens in VS 15.7.4 + R# 2018.1.2. Perhaps they should look into the problem, especially with those almost 14k who have found this question.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

1. Reset current keyboard configuration (Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard | Reset).
2. Go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | "Visual Studio"  | Apply Scheme.
3. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Choose "Use ReSharper command" in the opened popup(check "Apply to all ReSharper shortcuts")

Comment: Did the trick, but to have this finally working I also had to restart entire Visual Studio (version 2015 Community Edition).

Comment: This didn't work for me. What I had to do, was the exact same chain of events, except I had to do something in between points 1 and 2. I had to go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus, and then first choose the "None" scheme, and click "Apply Scheme", before applying the "Visual Studio" scheme.

Comment: Keeps happening to me in vs 2017. Might be related to updates, which are much more frequent now, and i'm sure i've ran into this same problem not long ago ...

Comment: Weird I already had "Visual Studio" selected and I just had to click apply.

Comment: I feel like I have to come back to this after every VS update to fix my shortcuts.

Comment: Life saver. Had to reinstall visual studio and resharper and my precious ctrl + t was lost, but now it is found.

Comment: As @TimothyGonzalez suggests, you do not need to reset (the scariest part). Out of the four steps listed, just do step 2: ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus | "Visual Studio" | Apply Scheme,  even if "Visual Studio" has already been selected. It will restore all the lost shortcuts.

Comment: For me it worked by only following Steps 2 and 3.

Answer (score 33):

For those of you (understandably IMO) not confortable with resetting all your keyboard settings for this specific shortcut :

1. Go to VS Keyboard shortcut settings (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard),
2. remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> assignment from the `Edit.GoToAll` shortcut,
3. assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> globally to `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoType`.

Worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me except I had to apply Ultroman the Tacoman's fix instead of step 3 (copy and pasted here): go to ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus, and then first choose the "None" scheme, and click "Apply Scheme", before applying the "Visual Studio" scheme

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, more targetted and less potential side-effects. What is actually hard with keyboard mappings si to remember the name of the specific action you want to bind. This answer gives exactly that. Thanks.

Comment: You do not even need to remove the existing assignment if any: skip the second step. 

Just go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and search for ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoType.

Comment: thanks man! you r the best

Answer (score 4):

Came back for me **without resetting VS keyboard mappings** (and loosing my shortcuts) by simply

1. ReSharper | Options | Environment | Keyboard & Menus
2. Selected Reshaper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA
3. Selected Visual Studio
4. Apply Scheme
5. Save

Comment: Might work just by choosing "Apply Scheme" too, but haven't tried. Next week I guess I'll get to try again ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not work, but other shortcuts does), but none of the solutions worked for me.

For my specific case, I had recently installed a VS extension (DevExpress) which apparently included another extension called CodeRush. Uninstalling CodeRush fixed my problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> not working.

If you have a similar problem, and cant seem to fix it - check if you have other extensions/tools installed that might interfere with VS/ReSharper shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in some cases it might be necessary to reset all settings of the IDE. 
This way I'm suggesting is the latest I would take, and before doing it, try the best answers provided before. 
However if you need to go hard, because <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not mapped correctly, go to ***Tools / Imports and Export Settings / Reset all settings***. Once done you can apply the ReSharper key configuration via ***Reshaper Options / Keyboard / Reshaper 2.x / Apply Scheme***

Answer (score 1):

What actually helped me was the combination of all the tips mentioned before *together:*

1. Reset all settings in: **Tools / Imports and Export Settings / Reset all settings**
2. Applying Resharper keyboard scheme, and than applying visual studio scheme in: **ReSharper / Options / Environment / Keyboard & Menus**
3. Only than popped up the shortcut conflict window, choose the **ReSharper command**

Answer (score 1):

None of solutions mentioned here worked for me. **Updating resharper** solved the issue in the end. You should try it first before resetting settings.

Comment: Update ReSharper from 2022.2.1 to 2022.2.2 did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out a funny coincidence that I discovered that my Resharper license was reset.

So, just a hint: check that your Resharper license is applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Vs 2022 config for shorcuts.

Tools / Options:
[image: Tools / Options]

Environment / Keyboard:
[image: Environment / Keyboard]